# How to plot two variables on same graph for different time periods

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I would like to plot rainfall and count data on the same graph. I have rainfall data for a longer time period (Jan 2018-April 2019) than I have count data (May 2018-March 2019 and I would like to show the rainfall data from the beginning of the year.

I am struggling to plot the rainfall data (blue bars) for the dates that do not coincide with the count data (black line).

Below is first 7 rows of data to show both

```
structure(list(site = c("KAHO", "KAHO", "KAHO", "KAHO", "KAHO", 
"KAHO", "KAHO"), ecat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("Low", "Med", "High"), class = "factor"), d = structure(c(17532, 
17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17652, 17683), class = "Date"), date = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 17682, 17682, 17710), class = "Date"), taxon = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "culex", "aedes", "aedes"), mean = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1.9, 33, 68), year.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2018, 2018, 2018
), month.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 6), year.y = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), 
    month.y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), mean_tp_rf = c(4.44880727132161, 
    82.5702138264974, 42.6738184611003, 45.8974380493164, 36.4939164479574, 
    36.4939164479574, 13.5674417495728), mean_tp_tmean = c(22.3933333333333, 
    22.6066666666667, 22.7246666666667, 24.1306666666667, 24.8953333333333, 
    24.8953333333333, 25.1926666666667), sd_rf = c(0.158071430694462, 
    3.91456178053996, 1.68735440125498, 3.08552737071039, 5.67905281150306, 
    5.67905281150306, 1.35057468784097), sd_temp = c(0.145340323117191, 
    0.155960923066676, 0.135744858711727, 0.14149541469939, 0.139788956577236, 
    0.139788956577236, 0.146358984626678)), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the column headers: Mean_tp_rf is rainfall associated with d, and mean is count associated with date.

```
'data.frame':   1164 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ site         : chr  "KAHO" "KAHO" "KAHO" "KAHO" ...
 $ ecat         : Factor w/ 3 levels "Low","Med","High": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ d            : Date, format: "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" ...
 $ date         : Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ taxon        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ mean         : num  NA NA NA NA 1.9 33 68 0.4 45.1 96.6 ...
 $ year.x       : num  NA NA NA NA 2018 ...
 $ month.x      : num  NA NA NA NA 5 5 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ year.y       : Factor w/ 2 levels "2018","2019": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month.y      : int  1 2 3 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ mean_tp_rf   : num  4.45 82.57 42.67 45.9 36.49 ...
 $ mean_tp_tmean: num  22.4 22.6 22.7 24.1 24.9 ...
 $ sd_rf        : num  0.158 3.915 1.687 3.086 5.679 ...
 $ sd_temp      : num  0.145 0.156 0.136 0.141 0.14 ..
```

I think it likely has something to do with the scale, or the fact that I have two different date variables within the date frame (d and date).

```
ggplot() +
geom_bar(aes(x = d, y = mean_tp_rf), stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "cadetblue3") +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=mean, color = taxon), color = "black") +
  facet_grid(site ~ ecat) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y", breaks = breaks.precip) +
```

[image: Here is an image of part of the graph I created -- It is just missing the Jan-May time period where I have rainfall data but not count data]

Comment: Hi Stephanie! Can you include some of the data in your question? use `dput`

Comment: Hi Mark! Yes, sorry about that, I have edited the question to include sample data. Let me know if that is not sufficient.

Comment: The data you provide is not sufficient, but I do think having two "date" variables complicate the work.